# Assume A is a set, prove that {a} ⊆ A if and only if a ∈ A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Unsure about proving "if and only if" questions!

Comment: Just use the definitions, my friend.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?  We can't help you effectively if we don't know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

An **if and only if** statement requires you to prove the *forward* and *backward* directions which literally means we need to prove

> If $\{a\}\subset A$, then $a\in A$

and

> If $a\in A$, then $\{a\}\subset A$.

The proofs should be very straightforward now.

Answer (score 0):

I will do one direction. Suppose that $\{a\}\subseteq A$.  We will show that $a\in A$.

We have $X\subseteq A$ if and only if every element of $X$ is in $A$. We are told that $\{a\}\subseteq A$, that is, that every element of $\{a\}$ is in $A$. Now $a\in\{a\}$, in fact $a$ is the only element of $\{a\}$. So $a\in A$.

Now I think you can handle the other direction, showing that if $a\in A$ then $\{a\}\subseteq A$.